# How to add to Java LinkedList while reading from a file?

Tags: java, loops, oop, linked-list, java.util.scanner

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

int maxSize = 10; 
LinkedList<someObject> fifoList = new LinkedList<someObject>();
int item = 0; 
int p = 0; 

try {
    scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        item = Integer.parseInt(line);
        
        if(p == 0)
        {
            someObject myObj = new someObject(); 
            //if the linked list is empty, add the item to the head of list
            if(fifoList.isEmpty()){
                myObj.setItem(item);
                fifoList.add(myObj);
            }
            else{
                //as long as the size of the list is less than maxSize
                int pointer = 0; 
                if(fifoList.size() < p0Frames){
                    //if the item is not already in the list:
                    if(fifoList.get(pointer).getItem() != item){
                        myObj.setItem(item);
                        fifoList.add(myObj);
                    }
                }
                pointer++;
            }
        }               
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File was not found");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for(someObject node: fifoList){
    System.out.println(node.getItem());
}

}
```

I have a file containing the following elements:

```
13
13
13
13
13
14
14
19
17
17
17
18
17
```

With this file input, I expect my LinkedList to contain 13, 14, 19, 17, 18. However, when I  print it out, it prints

```
13, 14, 14, 19, 17, 17, 17, 18, 17
```

Why does my logic only detect duplicates for the first number(13) but ignores all of the duplicates that come afterward? I also checked the value of the pointer and it never changes, so I am guessing that is also an error that is causing this. But, I have been at it for hours and cannot really figure out how to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got 14 compiler errors.

Comment: @Steephen sorry this is not my actual code. it's a representation of what I have in my file.

Comment: Please don't use representational code! Use the real code that you want help with. We'd like to help you, and you're handicapping us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of detecting the duplicate requires a loop by the elements in the `fifoList`, currently the value of `pointer` is reset to 0 for each element and thus only the first value is checked, so all the following values which are not equal to `13` are added successfully.

The code may be fixed as follows:

```java
someObject myObj = new someObject(); 
//if the linked list is empty, add the item to the head of list
if(fifoList.isEmpty()){
    myObj.setItem(item);
    fifoList.add(myObj);
}
else if (fifoList.size() < p0Frames) {
    //as long as the size of the list is less than maxSize
    boolean found = false; // flag if fifoList contains the item
    for (int i = fifoList.size() - 1; i >= 0  && !found; i--) {
        if(fifoList.get(i).getItem() == item) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) { // add missing value
        myObj.setItem(item);
        fifoList.add(myObj);
    }
}
```

Output:

```java
13
14
19
17
18
```